# Delegate doesnt work with SplitView

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a SplitView with master(left) and detail(right) view for an iPad app. I want that, when I do click on a button in the master view, this call delegate method on parent split view and push a new view o top, but the delegate method is never called. Why?

Here the code:

***Master view:***

```
protocol newAlbumDelegate{
   func openAlbum()
}
class newAlbumController: UIViewController {
   var delegate:newAlbumDelegate?

   @IBAction func buttonClick(sender:UIButton){
      delegate?.openAlbum()
   }
}
```

***SplitView***:

```
import UIKit

class AlbumSplitController: UISplitViewController, newAlbunDelegate {

   var newAlbumToAdd:newAlbumController = newAlbumController()

   //Delegate
   func openAlbum(){
      print("Do something")
   }

   override func viewDidLoad(){
      super.viewDidLoad()
      self.newAlbumToAdd.delegate = self
   }
```

Any help??

Regards,

Comment: I think that the error is that I'm creating a new master view, but I need to get the master view that it was created for the SplitView???

Comment: For readability, you may want to correct a typo in this question: "newAlbunDelegate" in splitView

Answer (score 0):

Within the `masterViewController`, assign the `splitViewController` as the delegate:

```
protocol newAlbumDelegate{
    func openAlbum()
}
class newAlbumController: UIViewController {
    var delegate:newAlbumDelegate?

    @IBAction func buttonClick(sender:UIButton){
        delegate?.openAlbum()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let splitView = self.splitViewController as! AlbumSplitController
        self.delegate = splitView
    }
}
```

Your `splitViewController` becomes:

```
class AlbumSplitController: UISplitViewController, newAlbumDelegate {

   //Delegate
   func openAlbum(){
      print("Do something")
   }
}
```